# Getting a record of all coredns records as a prometheus metric

Tags: python, kubernetes, coredns

Help with ideas how to implement sending all records that coredns receives as a metric in prometheus, I had an idea through a script to first query and then send to pushgateway but such an implementation limits me to record labels for each unit that I receive from the DNS list. I also had an idea to send unique records like AAAA or A from logs coredns, but no idea how to implement this mechanism.

I tried to request all records through a script and then send them to pushgateway, but ran into a problem with labels limitation.

```py
def resolve_dns_name(ip):
    try:
        dns_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
        logging.info(f"DNS имя для IP {ip}: {dns_name}")
        return dns_name
    except socket.herror:
        logging.warning(f"Не удалось разрешить DNS имя для IP {ip}")
        return "Неизвестно"

def get_instance_id(svc):
    return "some_unique_instance_id"

def push_metric_directly(base_metric_name, labels, value, dns_name, namespace, metric_id):
    metric_name = f"{base_metric_name}_by_dns"
    labels['dns_name'] = dns_name
    labels['namespace'] = namespace
    labels['metric_id'] = metric_id
    labels_str = ", ".join([f'{k}="{v}"' for k, v in labels.items()])
    data = f'{metric_name}{{{labels_str}}} {value}\n'
    response = requests.post(PUSHGATEWAY_URL, data=data, headers={"Content-Type": "text/plain"})
    if response.ok:
        logging.info(f"Метрика {metric_name} с labels {labels_str} успешно отправлена в Pushgateway.")
    else:
        logging.error(f"Не удалось отправить метрику {metric_name} с labels {labels_str} в Pushgateway: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config.load_incluster_config()
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

    logging.info("Начинаем запрос списка сервисов...")
    services = v1.list_service_for_all_namespaces()

    for svc in services.items:
        ip = svc.spec.cluster_ip
        namespace = svc.metadata.namespace
        if ip and ip != "None":
            dns_name = resolve_dns_name(ip)
            instance_id = get_instance_id(svc)
            metric_id = f"{namespace}_{svc.metadata.name}_{int(time.time())}"
            labels = {
                'instance_id': instance_id,
                'svc_ip': ip,
                'svc_name': svc.metadata.name,
            }
            push_metric_directly("k8s_service_dns_info_collector", labels, 1, dns_name, namespace, metric_id)

    logging.info("Обработка сервисов завершена.")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.